# JHipster docker image from DockerHub is not working

Tags: docker, jhipster

I am trying to run the JHipster in docker container and followed the steps mentioned in https://jhipster.github.io/installation/.

```
> docker pull jhipster/jhipster
> mkdir ~/jhipster
> docker run --name jhipster -v ~/jhipster:/home/jhipster/app -v ~/.m2:/home/jhipster/.m2 -p 8080:8080 -p 9000:9000 -p 3001:3001 -i -t jhipster/jhipster
```

As I am running it in interactive mode it showing the JHIPSTER ASCII art and shows `:: JHipster :: Running Spring Boot :: :: http://jhipster.github.io ::`. Thats it.

When I `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                    NAMES
f0015bd63658        jhipster/jhipster   "tail -f /home/jhipst"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   jhipster
```

Now when I try to access localhost:8080 I am getting **This page isn't working ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**.

I checked in my ~/jhipster folder, there is nothing.
I logged into container with `docker exec -it jhipster bash`, there is nothing in **app** folder.

```
OS: MacOS
Docker Version: Docker version 1.12.5, build 7392c3b
docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387
```

What am I missing?

Comment: at http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/JHipster you can find the steps and some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the JHipster Docker image, all of the software requirements are installed but you still need to run the generator and choose your options.

Following along the [installation documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/installation/), you should log into the container, change to the `app` folder, and run `jhipster`:

```
docker container exec -it jhipster bash
cd /home/jhipster/app
jhipster
```

Once your application is created, you can run all the normal webpack/gulp and maven commands.  For example, the following commands will start your backend and your frontend (run in separate terminals).

```
./mvnw
yarn start
```

Comment: Thanks John Ruddell. Its working. I feel it is nice to add it to official docs because it is a fair assumption that Docker image may contain jhipster sample app pre-packaged.

Comment: The problem is that after I stop the container, all changes and files that I added are deleted.
Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: @AmirChoubani When you start the container, you should mount volumes (with the -v flag).  The command in the original post and documentation show you how to do that.  Any generated files should be present in the ~/jhipster directory by default

Comment: @JonRuddell Yes, it worked know. I should mount volumes either by -v flag or by using WebStorm jetBrains.

Comment: It does not work for me :(
when I run docker inspect jhipster, I see this, the app folder inside docker container contains the generated app, but on my windows host, ~/jhipster remains empty
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "~/jhipster",
                "Destination": "/home/jhipster/app",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],